# How to display all fields for an entry within an entry field type?

Tags: entries, assets, fieldtypes, entries-field, sources

I've got a portfolio site I'm building, and on each project's page I'm wanting to show a list of people who worked that project. I created a channel section called "work" with an entry field type called "team". I then created another channel called teamMembers with a plain-text field for their name, another plaintext field for a link to their website, an assets field for their profile picture, and a categories field which would indicate their role in the project. When I'm adding a project as an entry in "work" i have an entries field that allows me to select team members from the teamMembers channel.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to display a list of team members (with each team member's name, link and photo) who worked on a project.

Here's my progress so far: http://dziey3.com/work/polaris

```
<div class="team-members">
            <h3>Team</h3>

            {% set team = entry.team %}
            {% for asset in entry.teamMembersPhoto.find() %}
            <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
            {% endfor %}
            {% for field in team %}
            <p>{{ field.title }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems on your website that you get the team listed, but not the photos. I think the problem might be that you are accessing the `teamMembersPhoto`of the `entry`, not the `team`.

You can try changing it to
`{% for asset in team.teamMembersPhoto.find() %}`